# actor:possible to send and receive nested in a receive

Tags: scala, actor

When process a message, is it possible to send out an message to another actor and wait for that actor to reply, and consume the replied message and then continue, like the following, is it doable?

```
val lineMap=HashMap[String,Int]()
receive {
   case bigTaskMap=> 
       for (line <-readSomeFile){
          if(lineMap.get(line)==None){
              anotherActor!line  // that actor will reply a hashmap which contain the key for line
              receive {
                 case x:HashMap => lineMap=x
              }     
          }
          lineMap.get(line) // use that value to do further work
       }
}
```

Comment: I think you should either look up become/unbecome or "ask". That is, if it is Akka actors. In scala actors, you just use "val reply = actor !? message"

Comment: Here is a link which contains details about "ask" which returns a future which allows you block and wait for the reply: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is for Akka** (old Scala actors are deprecated in Scala 2.10).

Yes. You can use `ask` to get a future (rather than creating a fully-fledged actor yourself) and then call `onComplete` on the Future returned to set an action which will be executed when the Future's value (or an error) becomes available. Don't worry about how quickly the Future might yield a value - it doesn't matter, because the `onComplete` action will be executed even if the Future is already available when `onComplete` is called!

However, be very careful: you should not directly access any of the state (i.e. the variables) in the containing actor in your action(s), because the onComplete action(s) will not run in the same execution context as the actor (i.e. they could be running at the same time as the original actor is processing a message). Instead, send further messages back to the original actor, or forward them on.

In fact, in some cases you may find the simplest thing to do is simply to send a message, and let the original actor handle the reply. `become` and `unbecome` may help here. However, again, be careful if using `become`, that in the actor's new behaviour, it doesn't drop "ordinary" messages that should be handled in the ordinary way.